# Why does background location not working in standalone build on android?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo-location to track user location while the app is in background. it's seems to work property in dev mode (using bare workflow and test with physical device) but when i generate an apk file, it's not working anymore.

in expo-location doc ([here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=performancemax&gclid=CjwKCAjwge2iBhBBEiwAfXDBR1DPCPi7ROqZmsibARfsVcvSSDZ8sNygsfTeR1ze3VnAmk8Y-i2iYRoCitoQAvD_BwE#permissions)) they mention that To use background location features, you must add the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in app.json and submit your app for review and request access to use the background location permission. ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION is property configured in app.json even in AndroidManifest.xml file but my app is not submitted yet on play store for review. can that submission for review be the cause ? if so, why in dev mode it's working property ?